# 301 Redirect every URL that is not in my htaccess to a particular URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm redirecting an old domain (jeans-vintage.com) to a new one (destock-vintage.com). Here is a snippet of my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/jeans-vintage$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# HOMMES

RewriteRule ^70-polos$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^68-hommes$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/7-vetements-vintage-homme? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^69-tous-les-$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/7-vetements-vintage-homme? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^71-t$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/23-t-shirts-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^72-c$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/25-chemises-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^73-pulls$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/22-pulls-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^74-bermudas-et-shorts$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/55-shorts-bermudas-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^75-pantalo$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/26-pantalons-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^76-jeans$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/9-jeans-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
...
```

What I want to achieve is redirecting every URL that is not specifically mentioned in this htaccess to the new domain root destock-vintage.com.

For example when I go to jeans-vintage.com/70-polos it goes well to destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage.

But if I go to this URL http://www.jeans-vintage.com/panier?add&id_product=3460&token=43e9dbbf254328614bc7b9512e3948e6 it stays on jeans-vintage.com and doesn't redirect to destock-vintage...

I hope you understand :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this with a **CATCH ALL rule** in the end. That end rule will only fire when URI doesn't match any of the top rules.:

```
# HOMMES

RewriteRule ^70-polos$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^68-hommes$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/7-vetements-vintage-homme? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^69-tous-les-$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/7-vetements-vintage-homme? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^71-t$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/23-t-shirts-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^72-c$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/25-chemises-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^73-pulls$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/22-pulls-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^74-bermudas-et-shorts$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/55-shorts-bermudas-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^75-pantalo$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/26-pantalons-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^76-jeans$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/9-jeans-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# CATCH ALL rule
RewriteRule ^ http://www.destock-vintage.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just have to put a last rule catching all the URIs at the end of your existing rules:

RewriteRule ^ http://www.destock-vintage.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]

This will not compete with the other rules because every other rule has the "LAST" option [L] (so if any rule match before the "catch all" rule, no rule will be executed after that).

Regards